# What date will be displayed in the commit history if you git commit a stash?

Tags: git

Let's say you have been working on a branch. You decide that you want to git `stash` your changes and continue working on something else. Later when you checkout on your branch to `unstash` your stashed work and `commit` it, what date will be shown in the commit history after you make a push?

Will the date be the time of stashing or the time of the actual commit of the unstashed files?

Comment: It should alway be the time you authored the commit, not the stash. Have you tested it out to see?

Comment: Once you unstash you're back to vanilla staged/unstaged changes.

Comment: Thanks! @evolutionxbox @Oliver Charliesworth Does this also refer to `shelve` changes? I know this functionality is IDE specific and not part of git, but is it the same as it is with stashing / unstashing changes?

Comment: Sadly I don’t know. I’m not a fan of how IDEs use other VCS names for git.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you `git commit` changes, Git has no notion of *where* those changes came from. Whether you modified the files in an editor, copied them in, or they got there from `git stash pop`, Git has no idea. Accordingly, the commit’s commit/author timestamp is wholly unaffected by the timestamp of the stash.

To change the commit timestamp to be something other than the current system time, something would have to set the `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` environment variable. The author timestamp can be set by passing `--date` or `-C`/`--reuse-message` to [`git commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit), or by setting `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE`.